# How to use list comprehention to equal to more than one variable in python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Suppose I have the following item

```
_example = namedtuple('example',['x','y'])
```

and I gather a bunch of examples like so

```
examples = magic_function_that_returns_a_list_of_examples()
```

I want to replace the following 2 lines

```
xs = [ e.x for e in examples]
ys = [ e.y for e in examples]
```

to something along the lines of this...

```
xs,ys  = [ [e.x,e.y] for e in examples]
```

To put it better words, is it possible to utilize list comprehension to set two variables at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just transpose the list of `namedtuple`s and unpack it:

```
xs, ys = zip(*examples)
```

For instance:

```
from collections import namedtuple

example = namedtuple('example',['x','y'])
examples = [example(i, j) for i in range(5) for j in range(5)]

xs, ys = zip(*examples)
print(xs)
print(ys)
```

Output:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Any solutions with list comprehensions are unnecessarily convoluted and would better be replaced by the two list comprehensions you gave. If you wanted to do it in one line, the clearest and most readable way with list comprehensions is

```
xs, ys = [e.x for e in examples], [e.y for e in examples]
```

However, `zip(*examples)` is probably still better in my opinion.

Comment: `xs, ys = zip(*[[e.x,e.y] for e in examples])`, May be this could be one of the one line solution

Comment: @AI_Learning Yes, I thought of that, but I realized that's exactly the same as `zip(*examples)`...

Comment: True. It might become useful / more readable if the namedtuple has more values than just two values